# Laravel 5 - Transfer MySQL data from Dev to Staging/Production

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, seeding

I am having this question that I have been scratch my head for hours...
I have build a Laravel 5.4 app that's ready to be tested on staging.  I am able to create the database and run migration.  So the question is how do I transfer the data from Dev to Staging, and later to Production?

I have a table called "regions" that lists out all regions in the area, such as "San Francisco", "East Bay", "South Bay" and so on.  I know there are work around like importing sql file or Laravel Seeding, but I just want to know the proper way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The SQL file would be quicker but in order to deploy and re-deploy having the data in a migration (or seed) might be better. Depends on how much data you have I suppose, or if you can write a script to make the migration for you.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you wouldn't *transfer* data from one environment to another. If you need to populate your database with data however there are a couple of approaches that you can use, which you seem to already have some experience using.

### Seeder

*Please note, a seeder does not work like a migration, a seeder will run every time you issue the `php artisan db:seed` command, which may not be what you want as part of your deployment process as it will often result in duplicate data. Its primary use is to re-fill your database during development. Since this is the case, I would recommend using a migration instead.*

I've seen many apps use seeders with conditional statements to decide whether or not to seed data based on the current environment:

```
class MyTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    if (in_array(config('env'), ['production', 'staging'])) {
        // Seed data for production or staging
    } elseif (config('env') == 'dev') {
        // Seed data only for dev environment
    }

    // Seed data for ALL environments (Production, staging, dev) etc. You get the picture
}
```

I've seen some create their own config items and helper functions to determine whether or not data should be migrated, rather than simply relying on the `env` config item too, so you would instead see something like this in a seeder instead of `if` statements checking the value of the `env` config item:

```
if (should_seed_data()) {
    // Seed data here
}
```

This adds a little more flexibility to being able to flag whether or not to seed certain data, regardless of the `env` the application is currently set to.

### Migration (recommended)

If you need to fill your database with data as part of your deployment process, like in your case you may be deploying a feature that requires a data table to be filled with regional data in order to work, I would suggest you do it as part of the migration process:

```
class YourMigration extends Migration
{
    protected $regions = ['East Bay', 'South Bay'];

    public function up()
    {
        // Seed your region data here
        foreach ($this->regions as $name) {
            Region::create(['name' => $name]);
        }
    }
}
```

The biggest advantage of using a migration over a seeder is that a migration is only intended to be run once. Once migrated, Laravel keeps track of migrations that have already been run and doesn't bother repeating them so you don't have to worry that the data is going to end up in there multiple times. A seeder on the other hand runs every time you run `php artisan db:seed` and it is typically something you wouldn't set up to run during deployment.

Ultimately, I don't think there's a *wrong* way to do it nor is there an accepted, standard approach to it so really it's up to you